# When debugging on WinCE, how can I set Visual Studio to always load symbol files it knows about?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I'm debugging a WinCE, C++ program in Visual Studio across an ActiveSync connection.  Every time I start the process it fails to load symbol information.  However, if I right click on the module and hit 'Load Symbols' it correctly locates the symbol information without any further prompting from me.

Is there a way that I can set Visual Studio to either:

- (a) automatically load this symbol
  information, or
- (b) automatically
  break the process into the debugger
  once it's loaded (similar to what
  windbg does)?

I'm guessing there's a setting somewhere, but I've yet to find it.

Update: I forgot to mention in the original question that I'm not debugging with the instance of Visual Studio that created the exe.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio should be automatically loading symbols.  But this can be disabled.  Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> Symbols.  There should be a check box saying something like "Only Load Symbols from these locations when specifically asked to".  If that box is checked then uncheck it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'd checked through those settings.  That one is unchecked.